# Gender Roles in Islam

Tags: nikah

I'm a muslim and I'm familiar with the responsibilities that both men and women owe each other, specifically in marriage. I was talking to a friend about this topic and he said that because the wife is obliged to take care of the kids and what not while the husband works, that this makes islam sexist because it's assigning gender roles. So, is this really a bad thing and how do we reconcile this statement?

Comment: Your question: **"So, is this really a bad thing and how do we reconcile this statement?"** is unclear. Are you asking if there are gender roles in Islam? (yes there are). Are you asking whether X is a gender role sanctioned in Islam (your comment **and what not** suggests that you might have a preconceived notion about some specific role). Are you asking if assigning gender roles is immoral? (that would be opinion based). Are you assuming that gender roles are immoral and asking for justifications (that would be apologetics and off-topic).